# How to handle home button press event in andorid for ICS?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I want to detect when user presses home key on ther device & want to take action accordingly.I have found this solution for this

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
        Log.i("TESTE", "HOME");
        openOptionsMenu();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);    
}
```

But it is not working for 4.0 so what will be the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {
        switch (keyCode) 
        {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                CurrentClass.this.finish();
                    Intent i=new Intent(CurrentClass.this,TargetClass.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    return true;
            default:
                    return false;
        }
      }
```

try to implemnt it, this done for me

Answer (score 0):

No. From `ICS` onwards, google has stopped using `onKeyDown()` once for all.